# Compiling into multiple .scss files with Atom Plugin sass-autocompile by armin-pfaeffle

Tags: sass, atom-editor, auto-compile

I am note quite sure if this is even possible with this plugin, but my current problem is that I maintain a large SCSS project, which has three sides and I actually want three different CSS files to be compiled while saving.

I have three main files:

1. core-something_1.scss
2. core-something_2.scss
3. List item

core-something_3.scss

All of there files need the same reset colors etc. This is why they are all in one SCSS project. To be able to compile I need to add the comment:
`// main: ../core-something_1.scss`

This will only compile one file, which makes sense, but is there a possibility to add smth. like this:
`// main: "../core-something_1.scss",  "../core-something_2.scss",  "../core-something_3.scss"`

The result will be that it autocompiles three files for me. Best case would be to get rid of these comments, and just auto-check where the scss sub-files are called and compile them. I used to work on "Coda by Panic" but swiched to Atom some weeks ago. In Coda everything worked fine without any comments. Maybe somebody can help. Thanks! :)

Link to plugin: https://github.com/armin-pfaeffle/sass-autocompile

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing right now.

Comment: No... not quite sure if this will work at any point.. Thy did not update the app for a while

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party but I may have the solution for others that complain that partial files and not compiling to the main file when saved.

I use this little commented-out line in all my _partial files. This tells SASS to compile the partials and add them to the main file:

`// main: main.scss`

Obviously, change `main.scss` to the filename of your main file and place this on the first line of your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to maintain one common set of colors throughout the site, wouldn't it be better to split it out into a partial and reference it into each of your scss files?

```
@import 'reset-colors';
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing, but I need this to be auto-compiled. I know how to build a large SCSS project. Problem currently is the autocompiling-plugin, not the concept ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Atom sass-autocompile settings select/tick the options Compile on Save and "Compile with 'expanded' output style"

Define the 'expanded' output style file path -> `../css/$1.css`

When you save/compile your main.scss file, it will create a 'css' folder into your main project and you will have an output .css file.

You should import all your `_core-something1.scss`,
`_core-something2.scss` into your `main.scss` file.

i.e

`@import "core-something1";
 @import "core-something1";`

You don't need to compile individual files you just need to compile/save `main.scss`

Comment: I get what you mean and I'm doing this but this is not the problem. Base problem is that I can only associate SCSS files to one main SCSS, but they should be assosicate to more then one main. e.g. main01.scss and main02.scss